# How to enable c++11 in Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, c++11

I use features from C++11 like std::function and have problem with building my iOS plugin for Cordova. Errors like:

```
error: no type named 'function' in namespace 'std'
```

It looks like compiler doesn't have flag for c++11 but I have no idea how to tell Cordova about this flag.

For some reason providing flag directly:

```
<source-file src="src/ios/Example.cpp" compiler-flags="-std=c++11" />
```

doesn't work and produce same error.

Comment: try using the c++ code inside .mm classes

Comment: @jcesarmobile I do this and have errors with including C++11 features like functions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm super late to the party, but I'm currently developing a plugin and facing the same issue.

It's hack-y and definitely not real, but a somewhat functional solution is changing the dialect and library flags in xcode directly. Please note that this may also mess with other plugins you might have.

Open the workspace (located at e.g. platforms/ios/HelloCordova/HelloCordova.xcworkspace) and then in build settings menu:

- Set `C++ Language Dialect` option to `C++11` value.
- Set `C++ Standard Library` option to `lib++` value.